# Self-dual of irreps of $SO(3)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I know that the irreps $\Pi$ of $SO(3)$ are self-dual, i.e., $(\Pi,V) \cong (\Pi^*,V^*)$. However, what exactly is the intertwining isomorphism $\phi: V\rightarrow V^*$?